# XMPPBOSHConnection with Smack 4.1.7 failed?

Tags: android, xmpp, smack

We have problem with this configuration for connected via http-bind to xmpp server .

```
        BOSHConfiguration.Builder configBuilder =   BOSHConfiguration.builder();
        configBuilder.setUsernameAndPassword("user", "pass");
        configBuilder.setHost("host.ltd");
        configBuilder.setPort(port);
        configBuilder.setFile("/http-bind/");
        configBuilder.setUseHttps(false);
        configBuilder.setServiceName("domain.ltd");

        Bytestream stream = new Bytestream();
        stream.setSessionID("123");
        configBuilder.setResource(stream.toXML().toString());



        AbstractXMPPConnection connection = new XMPPBOSHConnection(configBuilder.build());

        try {
            connection.connect();
            Log.e("alert", "connected");
        } catch (SmackException | IOException | XMPPException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            Log.e("alert", "problem : "+e);
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

and we try without

```
        Bytestream stream = new Bytestream();
        stream.setSessionID("123");
        configBuilder.setResource(stream.toXML().toString());
```

but still not connected to server .

we check the server connection with pidgin and other bosh connection is work fine

Error Log :

```
05-02 18:42:50.806: E/(32344): appName=com.example.xvdsdvdd, acAppName=/system/bin/surfaceflinger
05-02 18:42:50.806: E/(32344): 0
05-02 18:42:51.055: E/AndroidRuntime(32344): FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #1
05-02 18:42:51.055: E/AndroidRuntime(32344): Process: com.example.xvdsdvdd, PID: 32344
05-02 18:42:51.055: E/AndroidRuntime(32344): java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
05-02 18:42:51.055: E/AndroidRuntime(32344):    at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:300)
05-02 18:42:51.055: E/AndroidRuntime(32344):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.finishCompletion(FutureTask.java:355)
05-02 18:42:51.055: E/AndroidRuntime(32344):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:222)
05-02 18:42:51.055: E/AndroidRuntime(32344):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:242)
05-02 18:42:51.055: E/AndroidRuntime(32344):    at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:231)
05-02 18:42:51.055: E/AndroidRuntime(32344):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
05-02 18:42:51.055: E/AndroidRuntime(32344):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
05-02 18:42:51.055: E/AndroidRuntime(32344):    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
05-02 18:42:51.055: E/AndroidRuntime(32344): Caused by: java.lang.VerifyError: org/jivesoftware/smack/bosh/XMPPBOSHConnection
05-02 18:42:51.055: E/AndroidRuntime(32344):    at com.example.xvdsdvdd.MainActivity$deletechannel.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:82)
05-02 18:42:51.055: E/AndroidRuntime(32344):    at com.example.xvdsdvdd.MainActivity$deletechannel.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:1)
05-02 18:42:51.055: E/AndroidRuntime(32344):    at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:288)
05-02 18:42:51.055: E/AndroidRuntime(32344):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
05-02 18:42:51.055: E/AndroidRuntime(32344):    ... 4 more
```

Any Suggestion ?

Comment: You got any solution ?

Comment: any solution to this?? Any way found out to solve this would help me.